# laravel api resources autoincrement

Tags: laravel, properties, resources

how to laravel API resources add property in Row collection auto increment for row by row

```
"id"       => (int)$this->id,
"fullname" => $this->fullname,
"city"     => $city ? $city->name : 'نا مشخص',
"avatar"   => ($this->avatar()->first()) ? img($this->avatar()->first()->path, '124x124') : '',
"count"    => (int)$this->user_referral_count,
"rate"     => autoincrement
```

Comment: You need to do migration with auto increment for your id field not for the rate field in your table.

Answer (score 0):

if you set a field in your migration as `increments` it will be automatically incremented.
like bellow:

```
public function up() {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            ...
            ...
            ...
        });
    }
```

and after that, when you create a new instance of  `User` model. it's `id` will increase itself.

create new user like this:

```
$user = new User;
$user->name = 'hossein';
$user->email= '@hossein@k.t';
...
...
$user->save();
```

Comment: The column in question is `"rate"=> autoincrement`, not `id`